# Do people practice Polyjuice taking in ordinary life?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

In canon, we typically see Polyjuice used in generally extreme circumstances: camouflage for tactical advantage in battle; or spying; or theft of valuable property.

Do people practice Polyjuice taking in ordinary life? If so, what are the canon examples? If not, why?

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit that the question originated from a person (not me) reading fanfics where it was used for ... ahem... fanfic related purposes.

Comment: I heard that those fanfics can become quite, ahem, racy. */gets a touch of the vapours and goes to have a lie down*

Comment: Apparently you could buy the stuff retail; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/File:PolyjuicePotionLabel.jpg

Comment: @Richard - is that canon or movies or new wikia-like pottermore?

Comment: @Richard - my next question: what potion do you use in case of someone having a fainting spell? (Ale is NOT a valid answer)

Comment: Polyjuice, Felix Felicis, Amortentia... hmm, I think I see a pattern here.

Comment: @DVK - That particular label is from one of the film 'scrapbooks'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It’s possible, but we’re not told about it in canon.**

I looked through the books, Pottermore, HP Wiki, etc., and couldn’t find any mention of Polyjuice being used for anything that wasn’t in extreme circumstances.

That doesn’t discount the possibility of using it in day-to-day life, but it seems a bit unlikely. A few reasons that spring to mind:

- The potion is very complicated. When Hermione first reads the recipe, she says:

  > “This is the most complicated potion I’ve ever seen,” said Hermione as they scanned the recipe.
  >
  > — *Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 10 (*The Rogue Bludger*)

  The [Pottermore entry](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/polyjuice-potion) is similarly unforgiving:

  > The Polyjuice Potion, which is a complex and time-consuming concoction, is best left to highly skilled witches and wizards. […]
  >
  > it is a potion that many adult witches and wizards fear to attempt

  This means it’s probably quite expensive if bought rather than manufactured (assuming you can do such a thing), which limits the times you might use it recreationally.
- Things could get messy if it goes wrong. Hermione was actually fairly fortunate – she brewed a perfect Polyjuice, then just stuck in the wrong hair. Since this involves full-body transformations, it’s easy to imagine much more complicated scenarios where it goes wrong:

  - Getting stuck as the other person
  - Getting stuck as a weird hybrid of yourself and the other person
  - Bits of your internal organs failing to rearrange correctly upon transformation

  Possibly not something you want to use casually.
- Even if it isn’t limited to untoward uses, it seems to have those associations. Quoting from Pottermore again:

  > The idea that a witch or wizard might make evil use of parts of the body is an ancient one, and exists in the folklore and superstitions of many cultures.

  and the book with the recipe, *Most Potente Potions*, contains many gruesome and weird potions not suitable for polite society.

  Again, doesn’t rule out the possibility that it’s used recreationally, but that doesn’t seem to be a mainstream use case.

But perhaps it does get used in these ways, and we just haven’t seen it. The book’s protagonists were only children, after all. When they grow up, they’re at the mercy of fanfic authors… possible use cases are an exercise for the reader.